# Structured Logging in a relational database

Tags: postgresql, database-design, relational-database

How to design the relational database layout to capture structured logging?

**Usecase 1**

The output of sensors should be logged. Data: temperature and sensor-id.

**Usecase 2**

The duration of web requests should be logged. One entry for every request. Data: URL and duration

**Common data**

The two usecases are just examples. There could be much more. Each log entry should have a timestamp and a source-host column

**Relational**

Please don't tell my to use noSQL. This particular question is about a relational database layout. :-)

Our preferred database is PostgreSQL, but this should not matter here.

Comment: It is not clear at all what you are asking.  (And judging from the close vote, at least one more person thinks so.)

Answer (score 1):

In similar case I used, and suggest, separate tables.

If you can use postgresql, you can take advantage from inheritance.

In your case you can use a master_table for common_data and inherit the others table.

You wrote you prefer postgresql, so I assume you know, but, just in case: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/tutorial-inheritance.html

Using this you will take advantage of specific indexes in your data.

Another way is to use a single table with common data and other data in a json or hstore data, but this is close to have a nosql db. And no real advantages in this case, except faster coding.